# Passing PHP value as a parameter in jQuery and displaying that value in alert

Tags: php, jquery

Hello i want to display the value in alert . I passed the php value as a parameter in jquery and when i display that value in alert it shows empty 
**Code is  here**

```
<button type="button" onclick="topSharedPosts('<?php echo $postID; ?>')" class="btn btn-success" value="<?php echo $postID; ?>"> Facebook </button>
```

**Jquery Function**

```
function topSharedPosts(id) {
       alert(id);
}
```

Comment: (1) What is the *actual* resulting client-side HTML?  (2) jQuery isn't being used here at all, so that tag/reference/etc. is entirely irrelevant.

Comment: You should consider wrapping that $postID in htmlentities($postID) to avoid XSS.  After you load the page in your browser just view the HTML generated to make sure it has the value you expect.  If not, it may be your $postID value is different then what you expect.

Comment: Try  `ctrl + f5` cache problems ...

Comment: Code seems to be fine. Check  $postID, inspecting

Comment: thanks to all for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's working for me:-

1. your file must have `.php` extension not `.html`.

Check the below code:-

**Alert.php:-**

```
<?php 
$postID = 2;
?>
<button type="button" onclick="topSharedPosts('<?php echo $postID; ?>')" class="btn btn-success" value="<?php echo $postID; ?>"> Facebook </button>

<script type = "text/javascript">
function topSharedPosts(id) {
       alert(id);
}
</script>
```

Note:- there is no `jquery` in your code and my code. It's pure `javascript`. I have taken `$postId` value to check that code works or not, and it works fine.

Comment: @WaleedRaja most welcome. Glad to help you :)